# Strange artefacts in depth buffer with lines

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I'm extracting the depth information from a wireframe model rendering, and I see strange artefacts that I can't explain. To magnify the problem, I have rendered the model with a line width of 10.

We see on the exemple that they appear as strange little raised (closer to the camera) lines. Rendering the vertices as points works perfectly and rendering as polygons too. The artefacts also appear with a line width of one (but you need a magnifying glass to see them).

The colors read as follow: red is most significant byte and green is next most significant byte (bigger number is closer to the camera), I have removed the blue to try to limit the trippy effect.

[image: the little lines are not planned] [image: the arrows designate the artefacts]

Here is the shader I use to extract the depth information:

```
highp float factor = (exp2(24.0) - 1.0) / exp2(24.0);
vec3 EncodeFloatRGB(highp float v) {
    vec3 enc = fract(vec3(1.0, 255.0, 255.0 * 255.0) * factor * v);
    enc -= enc.yzz * vec3(1.0 / 255.0, 1.0 / 255.0, 0.0);
    return enc;
}
highp float DecodeFloatRGB(vec3 rgb) {
    return dot(rgb, vec3(1.0, 1.0 / 255.0, 1.0 / 255.0 / 255.0)) / factor;
}
void main() {
    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(EncodeFloatRGB(1.0 - gl_FragCoord.z).rg, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

the vertex shader is just:

```
void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

the online file is here: http://nraynaud.github.io/webgcode/test_wireframe.html
and the complete code is here: https://gist.github.com/nraynaud/825c62ca2e7ad8155e19

What could be causing those artefacts?

Comment: I have a compelling sign that those artefacts happen at the lines ends: if I draw the vertices twice on top of the wireframe, once without depth test and then with depth test (to restore the depth buffer), that erases the poky artefacts. But I have no good explanation for their original presence.